# Visual Studio Key Bindings - Have the same Key Binding do different Tasks with each Subsequent Press

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

In VS Code, the shortcut "Ctrl + A" selects everything in the document. I'm used to a more progressive selection system like Microsoft OneNote where Ctrl + A behaves the following way:

1. Selects the current paragraph (First Press Ctrl + A)
2. Selects all indented subparagraphs if applicable (Second Press)
3. Selects the current cell (Third Press)
4. Selects the whole document (Fourth Press)

In a perfect world, I'd like some method so I can rebind Ctrl + A in the .json file to do the following from just a default cursor position:

1. Select the current word
2. Select the current line
3. Select the current fold/indent section (may not be possible)
4. Select the whole document

I don't know if there is a command for selecting the current word. I do know there is a command for selecting the current line (Ctrl + L, expandLineSelection). I think the way I would go about progressively changing what the command does is by modifying the when section for each level of the command, but I don't even know where to start with that

Comment: ctrl+l is `expandLineSelection`. why not `editor.action.smartSelect.expand`, which is bound to `shift+alt+right` by default? does that not do what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[starball's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball) suggestion is close enough to what I wanted to achieve so I'm going to use it. To reiterate; the Command is "editor.action.smartSelect.expand" and I just edit the Json file to disable the original command and use the new command in conjunction with the default shortcut (Alt + Shift + RightArrow).

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+a",
        "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
      },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+a",
        "command": "-editor.action.selectAll"
    }
]
```